# php dot and mysql dot doesn't match

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table that looks like this:

```
|   vend   |   prod_name   |   price   |   qty   |
|----------|---------------|-----------|---------|
|   vend1  |   red wine    |   15.00   |    3    |
|----------|---------------|-----------|---------|
|   vend1  |  nike tg. 42  |   70.00   |    10   |
|----------|---------------|-----------|---------|
```

the problem with the code below is that when I update qty for red wine all works fine, but when I do the same thing with nike tg. 42 the update doesn't work. I think that the problem is that dot that I can't remove. The default charset of the database is latin1 and collate is latin1_general_cs.

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $DBuser, $Dbpass, $databaseName);
 $query = 'update prodotti set qty = ? where vend = ? and prod_name = ?';
 $st = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'iss', $value, $_SESSION['NomeUtente'], $key);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
 mysqli_stmt_close($st);
```

Note that I've already print $key variable and it is exactly nike tg. 42

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: This is why having an `INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` helps when updating specific rows. Keying it on `prod_name` is highly problematic. MySQL's string matching can be a bit loose at times. If you're incrementing and decrementing quantities, be aware of [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) that can result and *always* use atomic operations like `SET qty=qty+?` instead, applying differentials.

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prodotti WHERE prod_name=?` yield? Always try and attack the problem from a different angle. Maybe there's invisible spaces in there, trailing spaces, or something irregular that's confusing the situation.

Comment: yes I know but I have to use it because it is a school exercise and teacher wants that we use code that is in his slides (this is boring but I can't do anything)

Comment: count returns 1 @tadman

Comment: There's nothing special about the dot character that should cause a problem.

Comment: Your teacher really needs to learn the fundamentals of database normalization before going with a schema like this. Normal form isn't that hard and is a great way to teach relational databases.

Comment: The problem is not related to PDO or collation. Please copy exact value of prod_name from table and paste. Remember space between your string.
For your debug , echo in web doesn't show more space.

Comment: I've copied the exact value, still works for red wine and not for nike tg. 42, I've also tried to apply trim function for extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

use a query like this

```
update prodotti set qty = '11' where vend = 'vend1' and prod_name = 'nike tg. 42';
```

i only want to show to use that value you obtained in a **single quote** the above query i had given worked fine for me i think `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` causing error bcos u are not able to get single quotes with it  try with direct query and get value in itself try and reply if any error

Comment: I have to use a prepared statement for security issues